# Add base to permalink

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

Added 'custom structure' for premalink and placed '/mybase/%postname%/'

It is making all posts look like 'www.mysite.com/mybase/postname'

But it is not working for pages.

page name still remains 'www.mysite.com/pagename'.

How to change it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your functions.php file.

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_page_rules' );

function custom_page_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->page_structure = $wp_rewrite->root . '/mybase/%pagename%'; 
}
```

After put this code you want to save permalink once time in wordpress back end.

Comment: Worked like a charm !!! Thank you..... now is there any way that I don't have to go to save permalink ? means auto ? So I can put it inside a plugin.

Comment: Thanks but I Need to check for auto save permalink.If i can found something way then let you know.

Comment: To flush the permalinks or rewrite rules from your theme or plugin you need to use the flush_rewrite_rules() function.

<?php flush_rewrite_rules(); ?>

Comment: but running flush_rewrite_rules every time is not good, it will take too much resource.

Comment: Yes but without flush_rewrite_rules not possible any way.